# Asymmetric table projection in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Is it possible to have slick have asymmetric projects for `select *` vs `insert`? For example, this is what I'd like to do:

```
class Users(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(String, String)](tag, "users") {


    def username = column[String]("username", O.PrimaryKey)
    def email = column[String]("email", O.NotNull)
    def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)

    def * = (username, email)

}

val users = TableQuery[Users]

users += ("username", "email", "password")
println(users.take(1).firstOption) // prints ("username, "email)
```

Is there any practical way of making this work? The main issue is the insert, complaining about too many parameters because it doesn't match the projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but how about:

```
def withPassword = (username, email, password)
```

and then use as:

```
users.withPassword += ("username", "email", "password")
```

I believe that's the general approach to overloading the * projection.